# AWS RDS MySQL vs AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

### Amazon RDS MySQL vs Amazon RDS SQLServer

I have a data size of about 30-50 GB and its all in SQL Server 2008 present in physical servers. I am thinking of moving my data to cloud and I am considering Amazon web services as a solution.

Now Amazon provides both MySQL and SQLServer and I am trying to figure out which database is the most seamlessly and efficiently supported. SQLServer in AWS is a very new service. My requirements are following :

1. Scalability (should be provided for both the databases)
2. Replication

**One important thing is that recently there has been a lot of news about Oracle trying to kill MySQL . link  --> http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/18/oracle-makes-more-moves-to-kill-open-source-mysql/**

*What would the implications of this be on Amazon MySQl service. Also besides this I dont think integration of the current db into Amazon should be a problem but how well are both db supported in Amazon. I am looking for a detailed and clear answer. Thanks!*

EDIT 1 : I am still looking for a thorough answer. Does anybody have nay idea how well is SQLserver supported in AWS ?

Comment: Frankly I don't see that post as Oracle's attempt to kill MySQL. They did release a version and that actually had the bug fixes. Yes there are no test cases, but should that affect users who just use latest version of MySQL release? There is no change in life for those.

Coming back to topic, AWS have MySQL from very long time, and that makes it more mature. At this point, I would use MySQL over SQLServer which is too new just because of this.

Comment: There is another angle in AWS. You have option of RDS and DB installed on EC2 instance. The RDS performance is tuned in favor of `select` over `insert`. You can get better performance than RDS if you host your DB on EC2, and even improve it by doing the tuning work yourself. That can be DB tuning or EC2 tuning like using SSD, using provisioned IOPS, etc. Provided you have skills and time to manage your own DB, use EC2 hosted DB. But if you prefer managed solution, RDS is there.

Comment: @Ashish Patil - Agreed on your first point about Oracle but for your second point, just because SQLserver is new is not a disadvantage vs MySQL if it is fully supported by AWS. Thats exactly where my question is, how well supported is SQLServer on AWS.

Comment: To be fair, I do not have experience on SQLServer in AWS, and hence did a comment and not answer.

Comment: I would prefer managed skills. The first solution, though faster is way more time consuming and needs much more configuration.

RDS would be slower but still satisfactory for this project.

Comment: Thanks anyhow for your comment!

Comment: If you are on SQL Server I see little advantage to switching to mysql. Depending what features you are using, you may not be able to transfer everything between systems.